# sensorLandscape activity display very slowly when first run after first installer

Tags: android, screen-orientation

```
<activity
    android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
    android:theme="@style/WelcomeStyle"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
public class WelcomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "WelcomeActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    }

}

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/welcom_background">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bootImg_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/ads_show_anim"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bootImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adsCountDownTime"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/ads_accountime"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/channelApkDwnButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When my app's first activity set orientation with 'sensorLandscape', my app first running is very slow after installer. Who can tell me why and how fix it? 
Add one condition: my app's method more than 65k. When I set android:screenOrientation="portrait", the welcome activity's view will be display immediately after first installer.

Comment: Send also your main activity code. Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Add also the layout. The activity class seems to be OK.

Comment: @Fer layout has been added.

Comment: You have animations in the FrameLayout and also an ImageView that has to be scaled. I suggest you remove the animation, hide the image and check if the landscape mode now runs normally.

Comment: @Fer thank u, I'll try it.